# PHP Server Side Output Not Showing In Safari?

Tags: php, safari

This is more of a general browser related question than code checking. I have wrote a calculator function in `php` and everything works great in a traditional web browser on a pc, but for whatever reason my `ipad` will not display the calculated results.

I cannot share the all the code, but here's the bit w/ session data:

```
//Gather Form Data

    session_start();

    if(count($_POST) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['dob-month'] = $_POST['dob-month'];
        $_SESSION['dob-day'] = $_POST['dob-day'];
        $_SESSION['dob-year'] = $_POST['dob-year'];

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $_SESSION['submit'] = 1;}

        header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        die();
    }
    elseif (isset($_SESSION['dob-month'])||isset($_SESSION['dob-day'])||isset($_SESSION['dob-year'])){
        $month = $_SESSION['dob-month'];
        $day = ltrim(sanitizeNumInput($_SESSION['dob-day']),'0');

        $year = sanitizeNumInput($_SESSION['dob-year']);
        $submit = $_SESSION['submit'];

        /*
            Put database-affecting code here.
        */

        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }
```

Is there any other reason other than a possible error in my code that would cause issues w/ the browser showing the results?

I'm not receiving any errors, there's just no output.

Comment: This just crossed my mind, but it's acting as if the browser is not creating and storing session data as it does in chrome or firefox.

Comment: put this code:-`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` at the top of your php code just after `<?php session_start();` and execute. it will give you what error is occuring actually. thanks.

Comment: Please try my suggestion and check once at your end.

Comment: Can you share the part of your code that actually outputs something?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Part of the problem may be that I'm using ereg_replace to sanitize a string to make sure it's only numbers, but i believe that has been deprecated. What function should I use to remove everything other than numbers? I'm testing     preg_replace('/\D/', '', $c)

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I added both error checks as you suggested and it was reporting a couple erros such as undefined variables that aren't set until the session is created. I have resolved all the errors, but I'm still having the same problem. But for some reason the the page only works correctly in chrome.